# iOS: How to Preload Data before Display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, preload, appdelegate

In an `IPhone` app I am making, I have an `initialViewController`

(1) with a button. Once the button is clicked, it segues to another View Controller

(2), which at that point loads data from a `CoreData` File and displays it to the user.

My issue is that there is a small delay between the loading of (2) and the actual Display of the data. That is of course because the data takes a little moment to be loaded. I am doing it `asynchronously`, and my goal is to never show a spinning wheel or a loading screen (more user friendly).

What I want to do is to "`preload`" the data at (1), not at (2), that way data should have already been loaded by the time (2) loads and should be displayed immediately. **I know how to load the data at (1), but I have no idea how to easily pass it along to (2)**. I can't do it with a segue because my app is actually a bit more complicated than the description above and it's a hassle to do it via segue.

I have heard it is possible to use the "`AppDelegate`" but as I am new to programming I have no idea how to use it effectively. The online classes I've been following do not give very clear insight on how to use it, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I dont think showing a loading screen or spinning wheel is user un-friendly. Sometimes applications need time to do something. It is better to show that you are busy so a user knows something is going on in the background, than to just let them wait and stare at a non-responsive screen.

Comment: I agree. I intend to have a spinning wheel just in case, but I just want to reduce perceived loading time for the user as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment on Paras's post, I have a better solution for you:

Create a subclass of NSObject called fileLoader

```
//in fileLoader.h
@interface fileLoader : NSObject {
}
+(fileLoader *)sharedInstance;
+(void)createSharedInstance;
//add functions and variables to load, store data for use in another class
@end
```

Then,

```
//in fileLoader.m
@implementation fileLoader
static id _instance;


+(void)createSharedInstance{
    _instance = [[fileManager alloc] init];
}
+(fileManager *)sharedInstance{
    return _instance;
}
//other functions for storing, retrieving, loading, standard init function, etc.
```

@end
Now you can call `[fileManager createSharedInstance]` to instantiate a file manager that you can use from anywhere by calling functions on `[fileManager sharedInstance]`.

Comment: I also use something like this in my game, I have an audiomanager class that I share an instance with so I can keep a cache of commonly used sounds, among other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Property synthesize the `NSMutableArray` with you data like this.. in `yourNextViewController.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nextViewArray;
```

and in `yourNextViewController.m` file just Synthesize like bellow..

```
@synthesize nextViewArray;
```

and then just pass out like bellow..

```
      yourNextViewController *objNextView = [[yourNextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNextViewController" bundle:nil];
      objNextView.nextViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      objNextView.nextViewArray = yourDataArray;
      [objNextView.nextViewArray retain];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextView animated:YES];
      [objNextView release];
```

Also you can pass string or Dictionary instead of Array..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, you are passing the data along as the segue happens. As I said though, it's unfortunately not that easy in my case because I don't just use a single segue but several, and it's generally pretty confusing (I've tried doing it and it ended up really messy and I didn't get what I want).

So I'm looking for a way to do it without having to pass the data through the segue. Something I can get the data from regardless of the View Controller I'm in.

Comment: @Konrad , this code is useful about pass the data from one view to another so here you only one time download data from web and use it globally.. but its ok its good to solve your problem.. :)

Comment: WolfLink's answer helped me clarify your own reply, and I better understand what you wanted to say. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of DataManager object in which you store your data after loading it for easy retrieval anywhere in your app. If you only have to load the data once you could do it when the app starts.

The trick is to make this a singleton object so no matter where in your app you refer to it it will that same instance that already pre-loaded the data. I use these a lot in my project to manage any and all data that I need inside the app.

There are countless examples out there

Comment: That seems like exactly what I'm looking for (WolfLink's answer is very useful though, just not as flexible and I think this might be more useful later). Thanks for pointing out the use of singletons, I didn't know about them.

Answer (score 0):

The AppDelegate would be better suited for passing data from (2) to (1).  For loading data into (2) from (1), you can use the same function that you would use to load in (2) because (1) sees (2) as an instance of a viewController.  It is simply like this:

```
//In OneViewController.m
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];

    TwoViewController *VCTwo = [[TwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController" bundle:nil];
    //note that I am only instantiating VCTwo, I am not displaying it.
}

-(void)loadVCTwoFromVCOne{
    [TwoViewController preloadInformation];
    //simply call the function to load the data on the instance of the viewController before displaying it
}

-(IBAction)presentVCTwo{
    [self presentViewController:VCTwo animated:YES completion:nil];
    //when you are ready, you can display at any time
}
```

Comment: So this means I can "instantiate" my (2) prior to loading it, and then actually load it later? Well, I had no idea I could do that. I think that should work pretty well, thanks.

Comment: Yes, in fact I do a similar thing in one of my apps.  It's a game, and for loading levels, I pass the levelname to the game engine for preparation before displaying.

Comment: That's really useful to know; I had a lot of problems because I couldn't find ways to pass data from controllers easily... I'll keep it in mind in the future. Thanks :).